# Persistir array de objetos JPA

Tags: java, jpa

Estou tentando persistir uma `ArrayList` de `Entity` no JPA com o seguinte `for`:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("PU");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
em.getTransaction().begin();

em.persist(testCaseEntity);
em.persist(testTypeEntity);

for (TestPlanParamsSpringModel test : testPlan.getParams()) {
    em.persist(test);
}

em.getTransaction().commit();

em.close();
emf.close();
```

Dessa maneira **apenas a última** Entity tratada pelo `for` é inserida no banco, como faço pra inserir todas elas? Tentei [algumas soluções](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13580160/how-to-persist-an-array-list-of-type-entity-in-jpa) utilizando `em.flush()` e `em.clear()` no final do laço porém não obtive sucesso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possivelmente a coisa se atrapalha qdo vc tenta iterar o resultado da chamada do método testPlan.getParams() .

tire o `testPlan.getParams()` de dentro do `for`

```
...
List<TestPlanParamsSpringModel> params = testPlan.getParams();
for (TestPlanParamsSpringModel test : params) {
    em.persist(test);
}
...
```

acredito q assim irá funcionar.